# Google Chrome Extension Redirect different page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have popup.html I want to load different html page in extension when user click href. Example user will enter username and password and if they are correct login.html redirect to content.

Tried this:

```
window.onload=function(){
$( '#Login' ).click(function() { 
    alert('test');  
        chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
            popup:"login.html"
            });
        
});
}
```

## Login is a button.But login.html didnt show up. Alert is working.

Comment: What methods have you already tried? Where does the user "click href"? In the popup, page, extension page, ...?

Comment: As @Rob request please provide more detail !

Comment: If that JavaScript is running in the context of the popup, use `location.href = 'login.html';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the popup html page you can use

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup
```

more detailes on this page http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html

you can do something like this:

in html:

```
<a onclick="changePopup();" href="#"> change popup</a>
```

in js:

```
function changePopup(){
    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({
       popup:"second_page.html"
    });
}
```

You didn't specified where is the link placed? in the popup page or in an html page, so I assumed the linked is placed in popup html page.

If the link is placed outside extension, you should use Content Scripts https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html

**UPDATE:** You should put the java-script file in your manifest.json using background pages or event pages depending on what you need.

Here you can find more info:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html

```
....
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
....
```

If you loaded the javscript file from your html page using the `<script>` tag , you should use the Message passing api : http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html to interact with your html.

Comment: Your code doesn't containg anything novel that may solve the OP's problem. Furthermore, it won't work because of the [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<a href="another-page.html"><button id="add-button">Go to another popup</button></a>
```