# popup.html to redirect to login.html page in new tab window

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I have been refering to numerous posts and even went through submission

[How do I redirect the window that opened a popup window to a new page by clicking a button in the popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219480/how-do-i-redirect-the-window-that-opened-a-popup-window-to-a-new-page-by-clickin)

and

[Google Chrome Extension Redirect different page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829397/google-chrome-extension-redirect-different-page)

The code doesn't seem to be working for me . I am working on google extension to display a popup winodw which should redirect me to another page in new window/tab . I am using using Chrome on Ubuntu machine .

My maninfest file is :

```
      {
      "manifest_version": 2,

      "name": "One-click WebRTC",
      "description": "This extension is for 'browser action' with WebRTC.",
      "version": "1.0",

      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup4.html"
      },


}
```

My popup4.html file is :

`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Web</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 700px;
        min-height: 700px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin: 5px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadlogin() {
     window.opener.location.href="http://localhost:8080/project/login.html";
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body>
  Google Chrome Extension : Load ......................


<a href="" onclick="loadlogin();">LOGIN </a></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest, add permission "tabs".

Then use something like this to open a new tab:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://www.google.com'});
```

It's documented here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html